# Monetdb unable to execute queries with a where clause against remote tables

Tags: monetdb

I have been trying remote tables in monetdb. I have setup a remote table mapped to an existing table on a monetdb instance running on another host.

I am able to perform some basic queries, However I am unable to use the where clause: If I try to execute a simple query like :

```
select * from  "T1" where product_id > 1757;
```

The query execution fails with the error  (of course the query runs fine on the local table):

```
TypeException:user.l4[6]:'algebra.thetasubselect' undefined in:     algebra.thetasubselect(X_40:bat[:int],X_41:any,">":str);
SQLState:  22000
ErrorCode: 0
Error: (mapi:monetdb://monetdb@192.168.1.46/visokio) 'algebra.thetasubselect' undefined in:     algebra.thetasubselect(X_46:bat[:int],X_47:any,">":str);
SQLState:  22000
ErrorCode: 0
```

I receive similar errors on every query containing a where clause.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there a reason why I cannot execute a query containing a where clause?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are the two MonetDB instances from the same release?

Comment: yes, both machines are running the latest version of monetdb (as of this writing) Dec2016-SP1

Comment: That `X_41:any` should be int. It looks like a bug to me. You should report it to bugs.monetdb.org and include the output of `EXPLAIN select ...`